# NetworkX Export a Force network to XY coordinate

Tags: networkx

I'm trying so simulate my force network with NetworkX to get the XY position.

I have the distance between each node in my environment.

And I would like to have the fixed position in XY. 
Is there a way to retrieve my node data from the visualisation ?

For a simple example, 
I have my network like that :

```
G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge("B", "C", len="3.0", color="green", width="2.0")
G.add_edge("C", "D", len="3.0", color="green", width="2.0")
G.add_edge("D", "B", len="5.0", color="green", width="2.0")

nx.draw(G,vmin=0,vmax=1)
plt.show()
```

Which give me that :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts81Z.png)

So I would like to have my XY position of all my points.
If you know a way to achieve that, with this or another method, do not hesitats.

I really need help.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want the positions of the current implementation of Networkx force-directed layout you can simply call `pos = nx.spring_layout(G)`

When you use the function `draw`, if the position of the nodes is not given as second argument, the nodes are automatically layout using the spring layout algorithm (force-directed).

[See](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html):

```
pos (dictionary, optional) – A dictionary with nodes as keys and positions as values. 
If not specified a spring layout positioning will be computed. 
See networkx.layout for functions that compute node positions.
```

The code should look like this:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
# do smth
nx.draw(G, pos)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But It's not really what I want, because when I recompute another graph with the same "pose" it doesn't give me the same arrangement of my network. And when I compare the XY position in the array and in the graph it seems not correspond....

I just want the position of every nodes in my network after the simulation. Do you have an idea of how could I get that ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you want. What do you mean by if I recompute another graph? If you do the simulation yourself, you have the coordinates of the nodes no?

Comment: No worries. 
I take the pos as a dictionnary of my node position. But When I compare the position of a node and the same node position on a graph representation(plt.show()). It seems that the XY coordinates of a node, on the graph, is not the same that on the dictionnary.

Comment: Matplotlib can resize the figure to fit, or zoom in or out but the coordinates are the same. Also if you recompute another graph, make sure that what you call node 0 is actually the same as the pos[node0].